# If the Swift 'guard' statement must exit scope, what is the definition of scope?

Tags: swift, scope

I am confused about the definition of a code block or of 'scope'. Apple docs for guard say this: the else block of a guard statement...

> "must transfer control to exit the code block in which the guard statement appear."

Other [online sources](http://www.dotnetperls.com/guard-swift) say the guard statement must exit the 'scope' in which it exists.

So take the example code below:

```
func testGuardControlFlow () {

let x = 2
let y = 2

    func embededFunc () {

        if y == 2 {

            guard x == 1 else {
                print("oops, number is not 1")
                return
            }

            print ("from in embededFunc")

        }

        print ("I still want this to print even if x != 1")
    }

    embededFunc()
    print("Great, return still allows this to be printed.")

}

testGuardControlFlow()
```

According to my current understanding of 'scope', the code

```
if y == 2 {....}
```

creates a new scope, namely between { }. And given this assumption, guard would merely escape that scope. But that is not the case. Guard in this instance escapes from the function it is placed in, irrespective of whether it is buried in an if clause.

Am I completely misunderstanding what 'scope' means? Does scope mean the code contained in a method? If so, what is the correct term for the 'space' that exists within an if statement?

Comment: The requirement is that the else clause leaves the current scope.  `return` meets the requirement by leaving the entire function which certainly does leave the current scope.  It isn't necessary to use `return` in the else clause.  Other things will work, like `continue`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is totally possible to do what you envision, it just happens to not be what that particular code does. `return` always exits a method, not the local scope. To do what you wish, you can use a label, and `break`:

```
func testGuardControlFlow() {
    let x = 2
    let y = 2

    func embededFunc () {
        breakLabel:
        if y == 2 {
            guard x == 1 else {
                print("oops, number is not 1")
                break breakLabel
            }
            print ("from in embededFunc")
        }
        print ("I still want this to print even if x != 1")
    }

    embededFunc()
    print("Great, return still allows this to be printed.")
}

testGuardControlFlow()
```

To add on to [vadian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38958820/3141234):

`guard` forces you to exit the scope using a control transfer statement. There are 4 available to you:

- `return` and `throw` both exit the function/method
- `continue` can be used within loops (`while`/`for`/`repeat-while`)
- `break` can be used in loops (`while`/`for`/`repeat-while`) to exit the immediate scope. Specifying a label to break to will allow you to exit multiple scopes at once (e.g. breaking out of nested loop structure). When using a label, `break` can also be used in `if` scopes.

Additionally, you may exit the scope by calling a function that returns [`Never`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/never), such as `fatalError`.

This constraint is actually a good thing, and the reason why you might want to use `guard` instead of just `if`. It means:

1. It keeps you from check a precondition, but then accidentally go through as if you hadn't
2. It let's conditional bindings work better. Take this example:

   ```swift
   guard let nonOptional = anOptional() else { return }
   usesANonOptional(nonOptional)
   ```

   `usesANonOptional` would only be safe to call if it's passed a non-optional. If `anOptional` returned `nil`, the guard would fail, and would ensure you couldn't possibly call `usesANonOptional`. This means that `nonOptional` is known to be non-optional, and is automatically unwrapped for you.

Comment: I forgot to mention *why* you need a label to break from an `if`. It's really common to want to conditionally break from a loop. It's certainly much more common than wanting to `break` from an `if`. Thus, `break` within an `if` statement defaults to breaking the closest loop scope. Other behavior comes from explicitly specifying the label.

Comment: @Alexander - just wanna confirm - how does it work when used inside closures? does it exit the closure or the function inside which closure is implemented?

Comment: @PoojaGaikwad Just the closure. It'll make sense of you think of the reason behind this requirement: if the conditional binding of a variable `foo` fails, then what is the program supposed to do if it were allowed to carry on to a portion of code that presumes `foo` as a defined, non-nil variable? Think of `guard` as putting the rest of the scope in an "if let" block, whose's "else" block spits you out past the end of your scope.

Comment: @Alexander - Yes, thanks.. Just tried an example, worked as expected.. seems sensible :)

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of the term scope is absolutely correct. Basically it's the space between two (balanced) braces.

The description *to exit the code block* in the documentation is the most accurate.

To exit a `guard` statement you can use the *control transfer* statements `return`, `break`, `continue`, or `throw`.

- `return` and `throw` exits the whole function or method.
- `continue` and `break` exits the current scope (for example `switch`, `for` or `while`).

Answer (score -1):

You are misinterpreting what the doc says. The guard statement itself doesn't exit any scope. YOU must write some statement inside the guard statement that exits the scope containing the guard statement.

return will exit the scope. In a loop, break or continue will exit the scope. In many cases, goto will exit the stop. There is no specific statement to exit the scope of an if statement, so you would need a goto statement or something that exits the loop or the function containing the guard statement.

Comment: `There is no specific statement to exit the scope of an if statement` False, `break` can. `so you would need a goto statement` Swift doesn't have `goto`, but it's not necessary, anyway, as `break` is essentially the same.